# Why does my edit to nsmb.conf stop working?

Tags: macos, server

I am mapping a network server using a mac (MacOS Ventura 13.0.1), and the server keeps detaching (without throwing any sort of error) every 10-20 minutes or so.

I tried using the `nsmb.conf` file, adding

```
[default]
signing_required=no
max_resp_timeout=86000
```

and running

```
chown root:wheel /etc/nsmb.conf
chmod 644 /etc/nsmb.conf
```

in the hope that it won't detach during the work day. I need to be logged into our work VPN to attach the driver, and the VPN disconnects at the end of the day, so that seemed sufficient.
But every few days this will stop working, and the frequent detaching will start again. Running the code anew will *usually* solve this, but not always.

Why might the `nsmb.conf` config file stop having an impact, and is there a way to solve this?